# Intel NUC NUC6i7KYK doesn't boot, no power LED

Tags: boot, hardware-failure, intel-core-i7, post, intel-nuc

I have an Intel NUC NUC6i7KYK that yesterday just froze. I power cycled it and it booted to the login screen, but then the display corrupted and it froze again. A second power cycle POSTed and began boot but didn't even make it to the login screen before freezing.

(Oddly, nothing seems to be written to the syslog. I could have missed something, but I don't see anything out of the ordinary).

Now when I press the power button, the fan spins for about 10 seconds but I get no power LED and no POST beeps from the headphones.

I have a second, effectively identical system, which helps troubleshooting but hasn't shed any light on the situation.

I've tried:

- Switching power adapters (both work on the good system and don't work on the bad one)
- Switching SSDs (both work on the good system and don't work on the bad one)
- Switching RAM (ditto)
- Booting with no SSD or RAM plugged in (same behavior)

Seems like the system is just fried. Any thoughts for other things I can try? I can't easily make a warranty claim because I live outside the US.

Comment: It sounds like it's bricked how honestly

Comment: @Ramhound Intel seem to agree; they sent me a new one. If you want to make that an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ramhound said, the system was bricked. Intel support replaced it under warranty.